# Como ver se foi selecionado um arquivo em input do tipo "file"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Existe alguma forma de saber se o input do tipo file tem algum arquivo ja carregado, pronto para ser enviado?

Quero fazer uma condição onde se tiver algum arquivo para fazer upload no primeiro input, então mostre um botão de add mais um input do tipo file e assim sucessivamente.

É possivel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você só precisa, no evento `change()` do seu `<input type=file>` verificar o valor dele, se for diferente de vazio, mostre o botão de adicionar outro, que estaria até então escondido(suposição) e adicione um evento de `click()` a ele que adicione outro `<input type=file>` ao seu documento, que seria isto:

```
function verificaMostraBotao(){
    $('input[type=file]').each(function(index){
        if ($('input[type=file]').eq(index).val() != ""){
            $('.hide').show();
        }
    });
}

$('input[type=file]').on("change", function(){
  verificaMostraBotao();
});

$('.hide').on("click", function(){
    $(document.body).append($('<input />', {type: "file" }).change(verificaMostraBotao));
    $('.hide').hide();
});
```

E o HTML seria esse:

```html
<input type=file>
<input type=button class=hide value="Adicionar outro">
```

Com o devido css para esconder o botão:

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

## [Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VzfJd/2/)

Comment: É bem isso Paulo, só que assim.. se o cara clicou para add no primeiro queria que o botao de add + desaparecia  e aparecesse só quando o próximo input tbm estiver carregado. É possivel?

Comment: pronto @JeffersonAlison

Comment: Isso ai garoto, hehe... mais uma vez Obrigado!

Comment: Estou aqui pra isso :) Disponha

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o evento change do input para saber quando algum arquivo for selecionado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $("input:file").change(function (){
       var fileName = $(this).val();
       if (fileName)
       {
          // adicionar novo input onde você quiser
          $(this).after('<input type="file" name="'+$(this).attr("name")+'" />');
       }
     });
  });
</script>
```

[Referência no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670938/195417)... então vale a pena checar.

Answer (score -2):

você pode usar um onchange no input, assim quando você adicionar o arquivo será possível executar uma função, se você já tiver a função que mostra o botão pronta é só adicionar isso.

```
function addinput(){
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "file";
            input.name = "upload";
            document.getElementById("imgform").appendChild(input);
        }
```

pequemos essa função que gera uma tag input como exemplo

```
<input name="upload" id="img" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/gif" onchange="addinput()">
```

Quando o arquivo for adicionado o onchange detectara a mudança e irá executar a função addinput fazendo com que um novo input apareça logo abaixo

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).